# What is the etymology of ID (or I.D.), as in something used for identification?

Tags: etymology

Pretty much what the title says: I am interested in more information on the origins of the word (abbreviation?) ID, sometimes spelled I.D., as referring to something related to identification or identity. Most dictionaries say it is an abbreviation of one of these words. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/i.d.) says it's specifically for identification, and gives 1955 as the earliest usage. Can anyone confirm or correct this information, perhaps with better sources? Or if not, any ideas on where else to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most dictionaries state "ID"/"I.D." as an abbreviation for "identification" rather than "identity", so it's no surprise that Etymonline directs I.D. "specifically" to "[identification](https://www.etymonline.com/word/identification#etymonline_v_34531)".

E.g. From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/id):

> ID
> <sub>in American English</sub>
>
> <sup>(ˈaɪˈdi)
>
> *Informal*</sup>
> NOUN
> Word forms: plural ID's *or* IDs
>
> 1. identification
> 2. *US*
>    a card (ID card) or document, as a birth certificate, that serves to
>    identify a person, prove one's age, etc.
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 3. of or for identification
>    *an ID card*
>
> VERB TRANSITIVE
> Word forms: ID'd *or* IDed, ID'ing *or* IDing
>
> 4. to identify
>
> *Also* I.D.

"ID/"I.D." was used at least a decade before 1955.

From [*The National Magazine of Shipping, Volume 41*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=3EYfAQAAMAAJ&q=%22ID%22+identification&dq=%22ID%22+identification&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjhKjqwIj2AhVKEXAKHS4vC944ChDoAXoECAYQAg), 1944:

> [...] Next comes a visit to the I.D. (Identification) Room [...]

From [*The Hospital Corps Quarterly, Volume 17*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=xjwLAQAAMAAJ&q=%22ID%22+identification&dq=%22ID%22+identification&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi387K6w4j2AhUryIsBHY34ARg4UBDoAXoECAkQAg), 1944:

> 9. In the case of an unconscious patient, and search should be made of the clothing for **I.D. card**, billfold, letters, clothing stencils, etc., and as much identification as possible recorded on the tag. In most cases, some identification can be obtained In this manner.

From the [*BuS and A Handbook*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=AAVHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22ID%22+identification&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7o6P5xYj2AhUNBKYKHYRYBio4HhDoAXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22ID%22%20identification&f=false), 1944:

> NAVY IDENTIFICATION CARD
>
> If you do not possess or have not previously applied for a standard Navy Identification card, you will report to Room 1037, Main Navy Building, and secure a temporary badge for immediate use within the Navy Department.
>
> You will then proceed to Room 3523, Arlington Annex, and be photographed for your permanent **Navy "ID" card**. Bus schedules to the Arlington Annex are shown on page 24.

From [*The Code of Federal Regulations of the United States of America*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=MnXVAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA5758&dq=%22ID%22+identification&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3lceLwIj2AhXxs1YBHee2BREQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22ID%22%20identification&f=false), 1944:

> 21.39 *Property identification*. All livestock and issue therefrom and all major articles of equipment purchased with credit funds, and trust property given as security for loans of credit funds, except as otherwise authorized by the Commissioner of Indian Affairs, **shall be branded or marked with the letters "ID" to make identification permanently possible**, and certificates showing ac-complishment filed, unless the corporation's agreement with the United States provides for other identification. In addition. such property and livestock shall be marked or branded with the brands or marks of the borrower.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the *D* in *ID* is always capitalised, and why the abbreviation is pronounced as two separate letters, which all leaves an impression that it is an abbreviation of a two-word phrase.

Comment: @jsw29: It's not always capitalized, it's just more common to write it that way.

Comment: @jsw29: "ID" cannot/should not be pronounced as a whole word because then it would have a [different meaning](https://study.com/academy/answer/how-do-you-pronounce-id-in-psychology.html).

Comment: @jsw29: From Wiktionary: *id.*: Acronym of identity document; Abbreviation of identification.

Comment: Although it's pronounced as two separate letters, it does not necessarily mean that it's a two-word phrase. An abbreviation can be the short form of a word as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reasonably convinced that ID is the acronym for 'Identity Document'.  See [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_document)...